# Python Pandas date_range

Tags: python, pandas, date, range

```
dateindex = pd.date_range(pd.datetime.today(), periods=4, freq='W', dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

to generate some dates.

Can I get something like this to generate dates in the past.  I tried -4 but no joy.

Cheers
Kevin

Comment: do you want to generate four weeks of dates starting with today starting at midnight

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In date_range 2 of start, end, periods should be specified. It assumes your date to be start, unless you specify otherwise.

```
pd.date_range(end = pd.datetime.today(), periods=4, freq='W', dtype='datetime64[ns]')
```

You get

```
DatetimeIndex(['2017-08-13 13:18:39.525080', '2017-08-20 13:18:39.525080',
           '2017-08-27 13:18:39.525080', '2017-09-03 13:18:39.525080'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='W-SUN')
```